# I have Github Desktop installed, do I need to install Git to use command line?

Tags: git, powershell, github

I have **Github Desktop** installed and I see in the software there is a "**Open in Git Shell**" option that opens **PowerShell** in Windows.

I've been trying to use Git from CMD but it doesn't find it, do I have to install Git from https://git-for-windows.github.io/ this way I can use it from CMD?

Thank you!

Comment: why use cmd? there's 0 sense in that, powershell can do any cmd command and a lot more on top of that

Comment: ok, bit of noob when it comes to this.  how can i then launch powershell directly?  the only way, i've been able to is to keep opening up "github desktop" and opening it from there.

Comment: well, type powershell in cmd, click powershell icon, find powershell in applications and launch it, create an icon, millions of ways

Comment: Ok, thank you but how can I get "Git" to work from the version that "Github Desktop" installed?  Do I have to change environment path?

Comment: I use the [Posh-Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) module to manage Git in PowerShell. If you’ve installed GitHub Desktop, then you already have a copy of the Posh-Git PowerShell module and a portable version of Git installed which are located in subfolders of `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub` in your user’s profile.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes, you need to install https://git-for-windows.github.io/ You'll be asked how you want it to be installed (choose **"Use git from the Windows Command Prompt"**)

Once that is done, you can type `where git` in command prompt to see if command prompt knows where `git.exe` (the application you need) is. If it finds it, you can run git from the command prompt.

If you run into an error but, installed it, you may need to modify your PATH variable to point to the directory where git is installed.